# react-redux 4.0: testing mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

react-redux 4.0 now uses the context API, which is great! However, when trying to update a project of mine, everything is working but my unit tests starting failing.

For context, this is a very barebones "boilerplate" project I work on for fun. For demo-purposes, it is basically a to-do app (we all love todos, right?).

Now, for my containers I do some unit testing, but very basic. Basically, I want to make sure that both mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are receiving what they should be receiving. I don't care how, just that they are in.

Here's my "ConnectedToDos" component:

```
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'

import {
  addTodo,
  completeTodo,
  deleteTodo,
  loadTodos,
  makeGetTodos,
} from './duck'

import ToDos from './view'

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  todos: makeGetTodos(),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  handleComplete: completeTodo,
  handleSubmit: addTodo,
  handleDelete: deleteTodo,
  requestTodos: loadTodos,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectIntl(ToDos))
```

Now, to test this I used to do the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'

import ConnectedToDos from 'modules/ToDos'

describe('Connected <ToDos />', () => {
  const initialState = fromJS({
    resources: {
      todos: [
        { title: 'A todo', description: 'Do me!', id: '1', done: false },
        { title: 'A todo', description: 'Do me!', id: '2', done: true },
        { title: 'A todo', description: 'Do me!', id: '3', done: false },
        { title: 'A todo', description: 'Do me!', id: '4', done: true },
      ],
    },
  })

  let mockStore
  let store

  beforeAll(() => {
    mockStore = configureStore([])
    store = mockStore(initialState)
  })

  it('props should match mapStateToProps', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedToDos store={store} />)

    expect(wrapper.prop('todos')).toEqual(initialState.getIn(['resources', 'todos']))
  })

  it('props should match mapDispatchToProps', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={{ en: {} }}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <ConnectedToDos />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </IntlProvider>,
      {
        context: { store },
        childContextTypes: { store: PropTypes.object.isRequired },
      },
    )

    wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().simulate('change')
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit')
    wrapper.find('Icon[name="DELETE"]').first().simulate('click')

    const actions = store.getActions()
    const todosActions = actions.filter(action => action.type.includes('/todos/'))

    expect(todosActions).toHaveLength(4)
  })
})
```

However, this throws a nice warning now:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of
>   "Connect(InjectIntl(ToDos))". Either wrap the root component in a
>   `<Provider>`, or pass a custom React context provider to `<Provider>` and
>   the corresponding React context consumer to `Connect(InjectIntl(ToDos))`
>   in connect options.

Cool. But now I'm wondering what's the best way to test my containers?

I've tried a myriad of ways, the latest one looks as follows:

```
  it('props should match mapStateToProps', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedToDos />, { context: { store } })

    expect(wrapper.prop('todos')).toEqual(initialState.getIn(['resources', 'todos']))
  })
```

But it fails. It seems that, whatever I do, the `wrapper.context()` is always an empty object.

I can't copy-paste ALL my code here, but I have a repository that you can clone and play with yourself: https://github.com/enrique-ramirez/react-redux-boilerplate

The test that's failing is on `src/modules/ToDos/tests/index.test.js`.

**TL;DR** How can I test my `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` using the new react-redux?

Comment: react-redux-v6 required React16.4 as a minimum version, whereas you seem to be using 16.3. Updating that along with passing `store` to `connectedTodo` component in your test case `props should match mapDispatchToProps` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shubham khatri's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887623/react-redux-4-0-testing-mapstatetoprops-and-mapdispatchtoprops?noredirect=1#comment94637492_53887623) above didn't work for me, so I had to invest some time with this over the weekend. This is what I ended up with:

For `mapStateToProps`, I basically mount it within the required providers (for me it's the store provider, along with the IntlProvider and MemoryRouter; but the only relevant one is redux's `<Provider>`). Then I find the View (not the connected component, but the normal one) and extract all its props into a variable. I can then check each prop matches what I have in my store, which is exactly what I want to test (that props are being mapped properly from the store):

```
  it('props should match mapStateToProps', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={{ en: {} }}>
          <MemoryRouter>
            <ConnectedToDos />
          </MemoryRouter>
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>,
      {},
    )
    const props = wrapper.find(ToDos).props()

    expect(props.todos).toEqual(initialState.getIn(['resources', 'todos']))
  })
```

For `mapDispatchToProps`, it's pretty much the same as it was, but instead of passing the store in the context I had to wrap everything in redux's `<Provider>` or else it wouldn't work:

```
  it('props should match mapDispatchToProps', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={{ en: {} }}>
          <MemoryRouter>
            <ConnectedToDos />
          </MemoryRouter>
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>,
      {},
    )

    wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().simulate('change')
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit')
    wrapper.find('Icon[name="DELETE"]').first().simulate('click')

    const actions = store.getActions()
    const todosActions = actions.filter(action => action.type.includes('/todos/'))

    expect(todosActions).toHaveLength(4)
  })
```

I don't think these are the best tests, but they do test what I care about. If I ever come upon a better solution, I'll be sure to update this question.